# How do you pixilate a simple image in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, pixel-art

I have a basic logo that I would like to see with various sized pixels. I tried just shrinking the image and then zooming in but the reduction created reduced opacity pixels along the edges. I would like all the pixels to be solid.

[image: Original]

[image: Failed experiment]

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear: I WANT this to be pixelated. We want to make a representation of this logo using post-it notes. :-)

Comment: Turn off anti-aliasing in your resizing tools.

Comment: Its also posible to delete the alpha by duplicating the individual channel colors without resorting to a limitted palette.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the image to `Indexed Color` instead of `RGB` via `Image > Mode`. All transparent pixels will be removed and none will be created when the image is downsized.

Alternatively, you can duplicate and merge the downsized layer repeatedly. Even a pixel with 1/256th opacity will be opaque after 8 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your shape only contains 90º angles, it will have semi-transparent edges. The reason is that pixels are square, so Photoshop tries to compensate for half-pixels with transparency. I made a little diagram to show what I mean by half-pixels:

[image: Half-pixels]

Comment: @Tony Smith - thanks for clarifying that you want to make this with post-its, awesome idea. My recommendation would be using the original pixelated image you posted, and only use a post-it for a square that is 100% opaque. That should still give the same illusion from across the room.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to easy too me so I guess I did not understood it well :)

But did you try: Filter > Pixel > Mosaic?